# How to not redirect certain files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I recently set up my site to use HTTPS for everything. However, I want to selectively allow a couple of directories to use HTTP. Here is a snippet of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://phpbbservices.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
```

I'd like to exclude a directory like /httpdocs/digests/update_check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `%{HTTPS}` variable instead of the `{SERVER_PORT}` which is defined by the `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` directive, otherwise it may be inaccurate. For each directory you don't want to redirect, just add an exclusion condition (using the `!`) against the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/digests/update_check
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://phpbbservices.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not seem to work. I was thinking it was a file path problem, but I think I have the correct name.

Comment: This worked: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/digests/updatecheck/ Updated your response.